# Beamsearch with alignment_history = True(attentionwrapper)

Tags: python, tensorflow

tensorflow 1.9(and maybe some earlier versions) support using `BeamSearchDecoder` with the combination of `tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper` and its argument `alignment_history = True`. If using `BeamSearchDecoder`, output beams are ordered from best to worst. I want to know that if the `alignment_history` inside `AttentionWrapperState` is ordered or not.

** I found that the shape of `alignment_history` is [decoder_timesteps, batch * beam_size, encoder_timesteps]